# Funcionamento do switch case

Tags: java, switch

É possível fazer comparações com valores de variáveis na instrução `switch case` ou o `case` apenas verifica o valor de uma variável e faz uma ação? É melhor fazer este tipo de comparação com `if`?

Answer (score 5):

Não. No Java, o `switch` só funciona com valores constantes nos `case`s. Outras linguagens dinâmicas como Javascript podem usar variáveis nos `case`s, mas o Java não.

Um dos motivos é a forma como o `switch` é compilado - ele se torna uma tabela fixa no bytecode contendo um mapeamento (de-para) de valores inteiros para endereços de instruções dentro dos métodos. Uma vez que esta tabela está fixa e constante nos bytecodes, não há como ela depender de valores de variáveis que só estão disponíveis em tempo de execução.

No caso do `switch` com `enum`s, o compilador o transforma em um `switch` no `ordinal()` do `enum`. No caso de `switch` com `String`s, o compilador o transforma em um `switch` com os `hashCode()`s das `String`s (e usa uma sequência de `if`s quando os hashes colidirem). De toda a forma, o `switch` sempre será feito por meio de uma tabela fixa determinada em tempo de compilação mapeando-se um número para um endereço de instrução do método.

Assim sendo, a alternativa mais óbvia seria utilizar-se o `if`. Entretanto, outras alternativas são possíveis. Por exemplo:

- Transformar a chamada ao `switch` em uma chamada a um método polimórfico de algum objeto e transformar cada `case` em uma implementação deste método polimórfico.
- Se o objetivo do `switch` for dentro de cada `case` definir um valor diferente de uma mesma variável, pode-se colocar todos esses valores em um array, `List` ou `Map` e substituir-se o `switch` por um acesso a um elemento desse array, `List` ou `Map`.
- É possível usando-se um array, `List` ou `Map` de lambdas, implementar em cada lambda uma funcionalidade que seria referente a um `case`. Com isso, o `switch` seria substituído pelo acesso a um elemento desse array, `List` ou `Map`e execução do lambda obtido.

Answer (score 2):

O `switch case` é recomendado quando você tem estados definidos e apenas quer verificar se uma dada variável "casa" com alguns valores. Caso precise fazer alguma manipulação, você pode fazer antes de entrar no `switch case` ou então optar pelo `if else` para fazer operações conficionais mais complexas.

Answer (score 2):

O próprio `case` já é uma comparação.
Não é possível você comparar uma expressão com `switch case`. Ex:

O código abaixo compila:

```
switch(variavel) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Número 1");
        break;
}
```

O código abaixo **não** compila:

```
switch(variavel) {
    case (variavel > 1):
        System.out.println("Número 1");
        break;
}
```

Para fazer comparações como o segundo caso deve-se usar `if`.